# Including a formula based on a function in a dynamic defined cell

Tags: excel, vba

I need to concatenate a dynamic range using VBA.

My best guess so far was to create a function and then calling the function via VBA to a specific cell. Here is the code i'm using:

`Sub test()`

I used this method to declare the variable just to shorten the code. Basically the last column that may contain data will always vary and is never the same. I already have the code working in order to determine the last column that contains data so let's just say in this case the last column is column G (or column 7)

```
Dim LASTCOLUMN As Integer: LASTCOLUMN = 7
```

What i need is to get the concatenated range in cell A1. My best guess is the following code but i also tried several other options and all of them failed. Can someone please help me with this line of code? It needs to be dynamic in order to incorporate the dynamic variable LASTCOLUMN.

```
Range("A1").Formula = "=ConcatRange(Cells(2, 1):Cells(LASTCOLUMN, 1)" End Sub
```

This is the function that concatenates a given range

```
Function ConcatRange(myrange As Range) As String
    Dim CurrentRange As String
    Dim r As String
    CurrentRange = ""
        For Each cell In myrange
             If cell <> "" Then
               r = cell
               CurrentRange = CurrentRange & r
             End If
        Next cell
    ConcatRange = CurrentRange
End Function
```

Comment: `Range("A1").Formula = "=ConcatRange(" & Range(Cells(2, 1),Cells(LASTCOLUMN, 1).Address(0,0) & ")"`

Comment: BTW if you have Office 365 Excel you can skip the UDF and use TEXTJOIN():`Range("A1").Formula = "=TEXTJOIN("""",TRUE," & Range(Cells(2, 1),Cells(LASTCOLUMN, 1).Address(0,0) & ")"`

Comment: Unfortunately i don't have Office 365 and can't use TEXTJOIN. I tried your suggestion but it returns a compile error: "Expected: list separator or )"

Comment: `Range("A1").Formula = "=ConcatRange(" & Range(Cells(2, 1),Cells(LASTCOLUMN, 1)).Address(0,0) & ")"` missed a `)`

Comment: Worked flawlessly! Thank you man! :)